# Tilde do not cover all variable

Tags: equations, tilde

With this my equation:

```
\begin{equation} \label{eq:new-ri}
\tilde{RI} = \frac{RI(v)}{\hat{q}v^\gamma},
\end{equation}
```

I have this result:

[image: Tilde]

QUESTION: Is possible obtain a more large tilde which covers all the variable `{RI}`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation} \label{eq:new-ri}
\widetilde{RI} = \frac{RI(v)}{\hat{q}v^\gamma},
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect but... I must wait 6 minutes. :-)